# HTML5/CSS3 how to vertically align an arbitrarily-sized div within an arbitrarily-sized div

Tags: css, alignment, vertical-alignment, flexbox

I know that vertical alignment is an age-old issue and I don't want to beat a dead horse. But I feel like I've spent hours reading all of the clarifications and hacks, as well as what's supposed to work now with HTML5/CSS3 via flex box model, yet I have tried them all and still cannot solve this particular case:

`<div style="border: 1px solid black; width:50%; height:50%; margin:auto;">`

Notice when you resize your browser window, the div is always 50% the height and width of the browser window, and is always horizontally centered in the browser window. What I need is to get/keep it vertically centered as well. Is there absolutely any way, given that ***the div itself and the enclosing div are both of non-fixed (and unpredictable) heights***?

Please note the goal usage here is to have this div inside another div, however the my example here puts it merely inside the body in order to best illustrate/simplify/test the results given an arbitrary size of both the enclosing and inner divs via realtime window resizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use flexboxes, specfically the [align-self](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self) property. Since you're using relative sizes its parent element will need to have some height one way or another, e.g. via `min-height:100vh`, otherwise it will have no height that its content could align itself to. A body element by default only is as tall as its content, not as tall as the viewport.

Comment: those things are possible but weren't scope of the question. I recommend using some interactive flexbox tutorials to iterate through all the options